# Transformation matrix to polar coordinates

Tags: matrices, polar-coordinates

I'm struggling to understand the significance of these matrices based on partial derivatives, when the book I'm reading didn't make sense I found this article:
https://en.m.wikiversity.org/wiki/PlanetPhysics/Transformation_Between_Cartesian_Coordinates_and_Polar_Coordinates

Computing the transformations at the end via programming didn't clear things up and when I looked at the equation for theta at the very bottom I found that it is always zero! $-xy/r^2+yx/r^2$

However the book uses the exact same equations... What am I missing? Theta always being zero makes zero sense to me... Even if the x and y in the vector are supposed to be different from the ones in the matrix theta would be zero in lots of weird situations.

Comment: @AnneBauval Ok, I see your point... Not a duplicate but another reference. I agree!

Comment: A more elaborate answer why the transformations are what they are you can find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4311382/949989). Morale: it all starts with the good old chain rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the transformations at the very end of the linked article, as they are written, do not make sense. They should be intended as the transformations between the *infinitesimals* $(dr,d\theta)$ and $(dx,dy)$. For instance, the last one should be read as
$$dr=\frac{xdx}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+\frac{ydy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{xdx+ydy}{r}$$
and
$$d\theta=-\frac{ydx}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{xdy}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{-ydx+xdy}{r^2}.$$
This [webpage](http://math_research.uct.ac.za/omei/gr/chap6/node4.html) is much more clear in my opinion. Also the link given by Anne Bauval is very helpful: [How do you show that $d\theta = \frac{x dy - y dx }{x^2 + y^2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6083/how-do-you-show-that-d-theta-fracx-dy-y-dx-x2-y2)

Comment: Ah, then it makes sense that theta remains unchanged when x and y increase in tandem. Thanks!